# NetSuite Saved Search Case Statement

Tags: netsuite

I'm running into an an invalid expression when running this formula in a saved search for NetSuite.

The code should return a future date based on whatever the {entity} name is.

(In this case {entity} is the customer name on a sales order.)

The field type is: Formula(Date)

```
CASE WHEN {entity} = "Google" THEN {trandate} + 3 
WHEN {entity} = "Stack Overflow" THEN {trandate} + 8 
WHEN {entity} = "O'Malley's" THEN {trandate} + 2 
ELSE {trandate} + 4 
END
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Krypton, that really helped a lot!

I also had to change {entity} = to {entity} IN to get the formula to run.

Comment: Glad it helped!  You can upvote and/or accept to show it was useful for any future searchers.  Also, if you comment under the answer rather than under your question the answerer will get a notification to make sure they see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single quote for SQL string data, rather than a double quote as you have.  Then, to escape the single quotes within the string `O'Malley's` you need to double up the single quotes.  A double single quote, if you will.

So your formula will become:

```
CASE WHEN {entity} = 'Google' THEN {trandate} + 3 
WHEN {entity} = 'Stack Overflow' THEN {trandate} + 8 
WHEN {entity} = 'O''Malley''s' THEN {trandate} + 2 
ELSE {trandate} + 4 
END
```

Or, even better for this 'case' (forgive me), you could use a simple case expression, rather than a searched case expression:

```
CASE {entity} WHEN 'Google' THEN {trandate} + 3 
WHEN 'Stack Overflow' THEN {trandate} + 8 
WHEN 'O''Malley''s' THEN {trandate} + 2 
ELSE {trandate} + 4 
END
```